# php: constant variable attach with stdclass

Tags: php, variables, join, constants, stdclass

Is it possible to call a data from database by attaching a constant variable like this?

```
$table_result->description_{constant_varible};
```

So that the actual stdclass I intend to call is `$table_result->description_B;` `return '34'`;

Thanks

Comment: You should describe your problem to get better answer. Right now, The question is stand to accept either `'Yes'` or `'NO'` as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  E.g. via `$obj->{expr}`

```
<?php
$v = 'B'; // or a constant, doesn't matter
$table_result = foo();
echo $table_result->{'description_'.$v};

function foo() {
    $x = new StdClass;
    $x->description_B = 34;
    return $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work (not sure).
Here is an alternate.

```
$varName =  'description_'.constant_varible;
$table_result->$varName;
```